# Fetching user information along with user posts in Angular

Tags: typescript, angular-2+, rxjs

Here is my code with 2 services, one is `messageService` which is used to get user messages:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/retry';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import { handleError } from '../common/error-handler';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MessagesService {
  private _config = environment;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getMessages() {
    return this.http.get(`${this._config.apiUrl}/messages`)
      .retry(3)
      .map(data => (data && data['messages']) || [])
      .catch(handleError);
  }

}
```

And the other is `usersService` which is used to get user information based on `user_id`:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { handleError } from '../common/error-handler';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UsersService {
  private _config = environment;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getUser(user_id) {
    return this.http.get(`${this._config.apiUrl}/users/${user_id}/public_profile`)
      .retry(3)
      .map(data => data || {})
      .catch(handleError);
  }
}
```

And in the constructor of my component:

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'wall',
      templateUrl: './wall.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./wall.component.css']
    })
    export class WallComponent {

      constructor(private messageService: MessagesService, 
                  private usersService: UsersService) {

        this.messageService.getMessages()
              .switchMap(response => {
                let resArray: any[] = response.map(
                  post => {
                    return Observable.zip(
                      this.usersService.getUser(post.user_id),
                      Observable.of(post)
                    );
                  });
                  return Observable.merge(...resArray)
              }).switchMap(res => {
                res[1]['user'] = res[0];
                this.messages.push(res[1]);
                return Observable.of(res[1]);
              })
              .subscribe(final_post => {
                console.log('final post:', final_post)
              })
        }
    }
```

**The question is** how should I get user messages using `Observable` and then getting users information for each message (each message may have different user information), then merging them into one object which finally  will be used in the desired component with fewer `Observable` pipelines? I suppose using `merge` and then again `switchMap` to merge these data is not optimal and best practice.